# Можно ли в функции const char* присваивать литерал?

Tags: c

Вот так вот можно:

```
const char *str = "ABCD";
```

А вот так вот наверное нельзя?

```
void exmpl(const char *str)
{
    str = "ABCD";
}

const char *str;
exmpl(str);
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно и то, и другое. Все литеральные строки хранятся вечно.

Но в коде всё равно баг. Чтобы изменилось значение в вызываемом коде, нужен ещё один уровень указателя:

```
void exmpl(const char **str){
  *str = "ABCD";
}

const char *str;

exmpl(&str);
```

Answer (score 4):

Тип `const char *str` - указатель на *константную строку*, так что такие присваивания вполне допустимы. Вот если бы у вас было объявление `const char * const str`, то у вас был бы *константный указатель на константную строку*, менять значение которого после инициализации нельзя, так что проходил бы только первый вариант.